# How to get the object was pressed in a LongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView and i am handling the Long Press in the cells of the UICollectionView, but i don't know which cell was pressed. I tried to catch the cell indexPath in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath but don't worked. Anybody could help me?? 
Thanks!

Here is the method where I'm handling the LongPress

```
@IBAction func handleLongPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //here I want to get the item to delete

   // var itemToDelete =
    //context.deleteObject(itemToDelete)
    //context.save(nil)

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "My message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            self.numberOfCells = self.numberOfCells - 1
            self.myCollectionView.reloadData()

        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .Default, handler: nil))

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            println("completion")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell that was long-pressed in the gesture recognizer's action method with its `view` property. You can then use that view to get the `indexPath` with the collection view method, `indexPathForCell:`.

Answer (score 0):

There is really not enough information here to answer your question.

In my answer, I'll assume each cell has its own `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

```
@IBAction func cellLongPressWithRecognizer(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    assert(recognizer.view is UICollectionViewCell)
    let cell = recognizer.view as UICollectionViewCell
    // Yay, you have the cell!

    if let indexPathFromCell = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
        // Yay, you have the index path from the cell
    }

    …
}
```

If for some reason, you don't have the `recognizer.view` set to the cell, you can still make this work.

```
@IBAction func cellLongPressWithRecognizer(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    let point = recognizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    if let indexPathFormPoint = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point) {
        // Yay, you have the index path from the touch point
    }

    …
}
```